# Celery task calls endpoint. Is it celery or the django server that does the job?

Tags: django, celery

This is a generic question that I seek answer to because of a celery task I saw in my company's codebase from a previous employee.

It's a shared task that calls an endpoint like

```
@shared_task(time_limit=60*60)
def celery_task_here(some_args):
    data = get_data(user, url, server_name)
    # some other logic to build csv and stuff

def get_data(user, url, server_name):

    client = APIClient()
    client.force_authenticate(user=user)
    response = client.get(some_url, format='json', SERVER_NAME=server_name)
```

and all the logic resides in that endpoint.

Now what I understand is that this will make the server do all the work and do not utilize celery's advantage, but I do see celery log producing queries when I run this locally. I'd like to know who's actually doing the job in this case, celery or the django server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the task is called via **`celery_task_here.delay`**, the task will be pushed to a queue, then the **[worker](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html)** process that is responsible for handling the queue will actually execute the task, which **is not** the *"Django server"*. The worker process could potentially be on the same machine as your Django instance, it depends on your environment.

If you were to call the task via **`celery_task_here.s`** (or as a normal function) the task **would** be executed by the Django server.

Comment: Why would you call task with signature if it is not meant to be executed by celery

Comment: @iklinac if you need it to be executed synchronously within the same context.

Comment: If it is executed as function it is executed immediately no need to add .s()  (signature), as signatures are meant to be delayed, aka there is no point of using them in normal task invocation
( I upvoted your answer anyway)

Comment: this specific task is called by `.delay()`. But i'm more curious as `client.get(some_url, format='json', SERVER_NAME=server_name)` is actually where the heavy lifter is. I can safely claim that the jobs (say, bunch of calculations) are all done inside celery?

Comment: @JChao yes they are done inside celery worker process as it is sent to celery

Answer (score 1):

It depends of how the task is **called**

If it is meant to be called as celery task  with `apply_async` or `delay` than it is executed as celery task by celery worker process

You still can call it as normal function without sending it to celery if you just call it as function